# Switch component, cannot implement line with different shades of gray

Tags: html, css, reactjs

hey i need to implement a switch component that is kind of difficult,
i write in React so i will be happy to receive full implementation but if you let me know how to make that
line with the different shades of gray on it, it will be enough.
thank you

[the switch component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t7sJk.png)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to implement the color gradient of that block, is actually giving a background gradient. You have plenty of Gradient Generators out there, but here is a similar solution.

```css
.progress {
  width: 300px;
  height: 10px;
  background: rgb(237, 237, 237);
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(237, 237, 237, 1) 60%, rgba(148, 148, 148, 1) 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="progress"></div>
```